# Cache WordPress for offline use

Tags: cache

Client of mine will be out in the sticks and needs to have an offline version of her WordPress site. Is there a way to cache the entire site so that it is available offline?

I know I can use Xampp but she is not tech savvy enough and I am concerned something might go wrong at this event she will be at. If worst comes to worst this is the option I will take but if there are other alternatives I will appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use *[Teleport](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm)* or some other crawler to create a "proper" offline version of the website. However, if your client would want to showcase posting something or some other functionality that requires database interaction, then you're far better off using a local installation on [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or alternatives of it (enable Apache and MySQL to run as Windows services and make sure all the links in the local database point to the local URL and you should be just fine).

Also, if she has access to even a shred of internet connectivity, just make sure she has [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) installed so you could offer real-time assistance in case of emergency.

Comment: Thanks Thyamarkos, I will look into Teleport. She's since requested that it also needs to be on a Tablet so that rules out Xampp :/